# interrupt feature while downloading folder from S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, awss3transfermanager

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3 package to download folder from s3 but I am not able to find any method to cancel the download or interrupt the download process.

So how can I interrupt the ongoing download or stop the download process?
Any suggestions for packages offering this feature?

Folder size is upto 10GB and folder contains 1000s of file so it is creating multiple requests for same folder.

Comment: With that module, it seems impossible (based on current source). Have use tried the official [`aws-sdk`](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) ? `AWS.S3` class has [`getObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) function, which returns an [`AWS.Request`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html), which can be aborted

Comment: Yea but folder size is of upto 10 GB, and I need progress amount and interrupt feature as well. After cancelling download, if I start download then it should calculate file hash to download the left files. @pergy

Comment: I assume you have a connection that usually have .close() function. Or a request object usually have a .abort() function. Have you tried that?

Comment: @GillsoftAB, Yea we have that methods but at a time we have multiple downloading processes, so we can not abort request. directly

Answer (score 8):

I modified the code of the `s3` module to allow cancellation.

Here's the [PR](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/pull/219), but in the meantime you can use my [fork](https://github.com/marcosc90/node-s3-client) for testing:

```
const downloader = client.downloadFile(params);

downloader.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error('unable to download:', err.stack);
});

downloader.on('cancelled', function() {
  console.log('Download was cancelled:');
});

downloader.on('progress', function() {
  console.log('progress', downloader.progressAmount, downloader.progressTotal);
});

downloader.on('end', function() {
  console.log('done downloading');
});

setTimeout(() => {
  downloader.emit('cancel');
}, 2000);
```

What I added is a way to call `request.abort()` on the `s3.getObject` request.

Comment: this is fine but there is one problem, if I am cancelling one downloading process and just after that I am starting that same downloading process again then it is not working properly.

Comment: How is it not working properly? I tested exactly that, can you show what are you doing, or give a snippet I can try? This is a cancel, not a pause functionality. You have to create a new download.

Comment: It works great when I call the `downloadFile` method, but in my use-case we need to download an entire directory, so I call the method `downloadDir` but the abort process doesn't work for directories

Comment: Well, you should've said that you're using downloadDir method. That's why questions should have code. I'll try to check that method and implement a cancel too.